# не запускается сервер Фрида на Андройд, ошибка "Killed"

Tags: adb

Поставил рут права на Андройд, установил Фриду. Пытаюсь запустить через adb, после этого приходит сообщение "killed" и сервер не запускается.
Сделал все то же самое на Bluestack, там все работает
На физическом телефоне нет, мне нужно именно на нем
модель телефона samsung j6 plus, версия андройд 8.1.0